# ca id attribute be defined as php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following code in which id is named as a php variable

```
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","onlinetest");
      if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
      $table_space = "$school_name $class_name $section_name $mock_test_name";
      $table = str_replace(" ", "_", $table_space);
      $table_space1 = "$school_name $class_name $section_name";
      $table1 = str_replace(" ", "_", $table_space1);
      $table_space2 = "$table1 $table";
      $table2 = str_replace(" ", "_", $table_space2); 
      $table2 = strtolower($table2);
      $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM $table2";
      $result3 = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
      $question = array();
      $i =1;
      $section_id1 = array();
     while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
     {
         array_push($question,$row1);
         }
         foreach($question as $question1) 
      {
          if($question1['Correct_choice']==1)
          {
              $choice = 'A';
          }
          else if($question1['Correct_choice']==2)
          {
              $choice = 'B';
          }
          else if($question1['Correct_choice']==3)
          {
              $choice = 'C';
          }
         else  if($question1['Correct_choice']==4)
          {
              $choice = 'D';
          }
        $section_id1 = $question[$i-1]['Section_id'] ;
        if ($i ==1)
        {
            echo "<p style ='text-align:center;font-weight:bolder;font-size:40px;color:white;background-color:#3778BD;'>Section $section_id1</p>";

        }
        if ($i != 1){
        if($question1['Section_id'] != $question[$i-2]['Section_id']  ) 
        {
            $section_id1=$question1['Section_id'];
            echo "<p style ='text-align:center;font-weight:bolder;font-size:40px;color:white;background-color:#3778BD;'>Section $section_id1</p>";
        }
        }
             ?>
             <div id="questionpaper" style="width:95%;border:4px solid gray;padding:7px;margin:30px;background-color: white ">

     <span style="font-size:18px;color:darkorange;text-align:center;font-weight:bolder;display:block"> CLICK TO EDIT</span>       

             <p contenteditable="true" id="question:<?php $i ?>" style="width:96%;border:4px thin black; ;font-size:18px;background-color:#1c86ee;color:WHITE;-moz-border-radius:12px;-webkit-border-radius:12px;border-radius:12px;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px "><?php echo $i.'.'.'&nbsp;'.$question1['question'];?></p>
  <p contenteditable="true" id="Option1" style="width:98%;border:4px thin black; background-color:#D6D6D6;font-size:18px;color:black;padding:3px "><?php echo '&nbsp;'.'A.'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp'.$question1['Option1'];?></p> 
  <p  contenteditable="true" id="<?php echo "Option2_$i"; ?>" style="width:98%;border:4px thin black; background-color:#D6D6D6;font-size:18px;color:black;padding:3px "><?php echo '&nbsp;'.'B.'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp'.$question1['Option2'];?></P> 
  <p contenteditable="true" id="Option3:<?php $i ?>" style="width:98%;border:4px thin black; background-color:#D6D6D6;font-size:18px;color:black;padding:3px "><?php echo '&nbsp;'.'C.'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp'.$question1['Option3'];?></p>
   <p contenteditable="true" id="Option4:<?php $i ?>" style="width:98%;border:4px thin black; background-color:#D6D6D6;font-size:18px;color:black;padding:3px "><?php echo '&nbsp;'.'D.'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp'.$question1['Option4'];?></p> 
  <p contenteditable="true" id="Correct_choice:<?php $i ?>" style="width:98%;border:4px thin black; background-color:#1c86ee;font-size:18px;color:white;padding:3px "><?php echo '&nbsp;'.'Correct'.'&nbsp;'. 'Choice'.'&nbsp;'.':'.'&nbsp;'.'Option'.'&nbsp;'.$choice;?></p>


             </div>
             <br /><br />
             <?php
             $i++;

          }
}
```

here $i is a variable and its value increases in a loop

and then javascript code am using is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = run;
function run()
{
    for(var i=0;i<=3;i++)
    document.getElementById("Option2:" + i).innerHTML = "done" + i  ;
}

</script>
```

But the above js code is not working. please help me?

Comment: is this really a minimum example? what do you mean with "not working"? (be more specific)

Answer (score 0):

Make following corrections:

```
    <p contenteditable="true" id="Option1_<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:98%;border:4px thin black; background-color:#D6D6D6;font-size:18px;color:black;padding:3px "><?php echo '&nbsp;'.'A.'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp'.$question1['Option1'];?></p> 
      <p  contenteditable="true" id="Option2_<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:98%;border:4px thin black; background-color:#D6D6D6;font-size:18px;color:black;padding:3px "><?php echo '&nbsp;'.'B.'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp'.$question1['Option2'];?></P> 
      <p contenteditable="true" id="Option3_<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:98%;border:4px thin black; background-color:#D6D6D6;font-size:18px;color:black;padding:3px "><?php echo '&nbsp;'.'C.'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp'.$question1['Option3'];?></p>
       <p contenteditable="true" id="Option4_<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:98%;border:4px thin black; background-color:#D6D6D6;font-size:18px;color:black;padding:3px "><?php echo '&nbsp;'.'D.'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp'.$question1['Option4'];?></p>
```

and

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = run;
    function run()
    {
        for(var i=1;i<=4;i++) {
            var option = document.getElementById("Option2:" + i);
            if( option ) // make sure that element with matching id exist, so that we can access it's properties.
                option.innerHTML = "done" + i  ;
        }
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Try placing script after </body> tag, and directly calling run. also if you can post more detailed code in php (including loop condition) it will be easier to help